# Как сделать поиск в Django Python

Tags: django

У меня есть такая форма в base.html

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="{% url 'blog-home' %}">
  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search"name="search">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Поиcк /button>
</form>
```

А также views.py

```
def home(request):

    search_query = request.GET.get('search', '')

    if search_query:
        posts = Post.objects.filter(title__icontains=search_query)
    else:
        posts = Post.objects.all()

    context = {
        'posts': POst.object.all()

    }
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)
```

это не работает помогите сделать поиск

Answer (score 1):

конечно это не будет работать

```
 context = {
    'posts': POst.object.all()
}
```

вы же возвращаете все объекты в шаблон , удалите эту строчку
и в return

```
 return render(request, 'blog/home.html', {'post':post})
```

ну или хотя бы

```
context = {
    'posts': post
}
return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)
```